# Typescript http get request

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to edit code for a school club that utilizes angular 2 and I need to make a http get request within a component.ts file. I don't need to grab any information from it, since it's only sending a request to a server that's listening for the request. Tried multiple methods from googling but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HTTP Gets via the `fetch()` API

### Node.js

Node does not have `fetch` natively. Install `node-fetch` and use it as so:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// in an async function...
await fetch('URL').then(res => res.text());
```

### Browsers

This is pretty simple:

```js
// in an async function...
await fetch('URL').then(res => res.text());
```

Comment: I can't seem to use "const fetch = require('node-fetch');, do you know how to use that as an import statement for typescript files?

Comment: if you are using angular you need the browser one as angular is a frontend framework isn't it? for import its `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`

Comment: I wish I knew unfortunately, I know if I use that import statement it just says it cannot find module node-fetch.

Comment: I believe I need a module from angular, such as "import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'"

Comment: @a_polo **You are on the frontend. The node-fetch module is for Node.js (the backend) as I said.** `fetch()` is builtin on browsers. Read the second part.

Comment: can I just use fetch('URL') if all I need is a simple request and it's not in an asynchronous function?

Comment: @a_polo: if you don't use await or .then, it will just run in the background (your code will continue whilst the request is running)